# Hyphenation doesn´t work with dita-ot 2.5.1 and Apache FOP

Tags: pdf, apache-fop, dita-ot

I use dita-ot to render to pdf.
Recently, I upgraded from dita-ot 1.8.M2 to 2.5.1
Updating my pdf plugins was quite a bit of work, but the only thing that I don´t get to work properly is hyphenation.

I did it all as described on the [Apache website](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/hyphenation.html).

The relevant instruction in detail:

> "Download the precompiled JAR from OFFO and place it either in the
>   {fop-dir}/lib directory, or in a directory of your choice (and append
>   the full path to the JAR to the environment variable
>   FOP_HYPHENATION_PATH)."

That is how it worked with dita-ot 1.8.M2, where the {fop-dir} was placed in the "org.dita.pdf2" plugin.
Now, {fop-dir} is in the "org.dita.pdf2.fop" plugin. Maybe this is the reason, why "fop-hyph.jar" is obviously not found by the process? But what about the environment variable?

Has anybody a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself: I just added the attribute `<xsl:attribute name="hyphenate">true</xsl:attribute>` to the attribute set `common.block` inside of the attribute file `commons-attr.xsl`.

I found out that not FOP or the jar file is the cause, when I compared a FO file generated with the old dita-ot (with hyphenation) to a FO file of the new dita-ot. What was missing was the `hyphenate=true` attribute in each block.

Thanks for your patience!

Comment: A comment by myself: When using the `dita` command, the required file "fop-hyph.jar" isn´t automatically found (even if the environment variable "path" points to it). So set the appropriate classpath in your batch file: `set CLASSPATH=%DITA_DIR%plugins\org.dita.pdf2.fop\fop\lib\fop-hyph.jar;%CLASSPATH%`